# Combine multiple ggpredict plots in one

Tags: r, plot

I build a model with the lmer-fuction (m1). Now I want to plot the predicting values. I used this code:

```
p1 <- ggpredict(m1, "variable1")
p2 <- ggpredict(m1, "variable2")
p3 <- ggpredict(m1, "variable3")
```

With plot(p1) I would get the single plot as output. But I want that all three plots are visualized in one. Is there a way to overlay/combine them?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `patchwork` to arrange multiple plots

```
library(patchwork)
p1|p2|p3
```